# React Components not showing using Router, Route, Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React Components not showing using Router, Route, Link

By clicking the Menu button I can tell from the URL: "http://localhost:3000/Menu", that I have linked  to the right route. However, the Menu component just won't show up.

Here is the code for my NavBar Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './index.css'
import logo from '../../image/laoma-logo.png'
import {NavItems} from "./NavItems/NavItems";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class HeaderNav extends Component {
    state = {clicked: false}

    handleClick = () =>{
        this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="NavItems">
                <div>
                    <img className="NavLogo" src={logo} alt='LaoMa Logo'/>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times':'fas fa-bars'}>
                    </i>
                </div>
                <ul className={this.state.clicked? 'nav-menu active': 'nav-menu'}>
                    {NavItems.map((item, index)=> {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <Link className={item.cName} href={item.url} to={item.title}>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>

        );
    }
}

export default HeaderNav;
```

Here is my Menu component,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import items from "../../../data/items";
import Categories from "./Categories";
import Items from "./Items";
import './index.css'

const allCategories = ['all', ...new Set(items.map((item) => item.category))];

function Menu() {
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(items);
    const [categories] = useState(allCategories);

    const filterItems = (category) => {
        if (category === 'all') {
            setMenuItems(items);
            return;
        }
        const newItems = items.filter((item) => item.category === category);
        setMenuItems(newItems);
    };

    return (
        <main>
            {/* <Route path={NavItems.title} component={Menu}/> */}
            <section className='menu section'>
                <Categories categories={categories} filterItems={filterItems}/>
                <Items items={menuItems}/>
            </section>
        </main>
    );
}


export default Menu;
```

Here is my App components:

```
import HeaderNav from './components/HeaderNav/index';
import {Component} from "react";
import { BrowerRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Menu from './components/Body/Menu';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <HeaderNav/>
                        <Route path='/Menu'>
                            <Menu/>
                        </Route>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Just from the sake of completion, here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Repeated question

Comment: It seems to be working, checkout this https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-forest-6njse?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @WaelZoaiter Yours does work. However, it doesn't work from mine. I guess the problem is within my <Link> element, where I try to use an object for "to="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I should use `exact path=''` instead of `path=''` because how router works is that it will go through every routes and apply the very first one in the list. And with partial matching, it will return the component or page pf the first nested route, and here 'exact' comes into play and solve the issue.